# How to prove that a circle inscribed in a sphere will remain a circle after a random movement

Tags: geometry, 3d

I'm trying to prove Euler's theorem for rigid bodys (in 3-D space of course).

I would like to prove the following: given a sphere $\mathcal S$ and circle $\gamma \subset \mathcal S$, assuming $\mathcal S$ is a rigid body (i.e. all the points keep their relative position in between each other during the movement) prove that the image of $\gamma$ in any kind of movement of the sphere is a new circle $\gamma' \subset \mathcal S$.

I'm running away from calculations, as much as I can.

What I've thought: take any three points $A,B$ and $C$ in $\gamma$ and let their images be $A',B'$ and $C'$ respectively, these last three points define a plane and thus a new circle $\omega \subset \mathcal S$.

Because of the rigid body condition: $AB=A'B', BC=B'C'$ and $AC = A'C'$, $\triangle ABC \cong \triangle A'B'C'$ and thus their circumcircles are congruent: $\omega \cong \gamma$

On my last step I wanted to asume point $D \in \gamma$ goes to $D' \notin \omega$ and get a contradiction, but I'm struggling to formalize it.

Of course, $D'$ is not in $\omega$ iff $D'$ is not on the plane defined by $A'B'C'$, can we prove that $D'$ outside this plane implies $D'A \neq DA$?

I'm looking for a geometric proof that an isometry will preserve the circle in a sphere

Comment: Consider that "rigid motion" means, in particular, that distances between points are not changed. Then use the definition of a circle and the locus of all points equidistant from a given point (both in the metric on the sphere, and in the ambient 3D space.

Comment: but the center of the circle is not necessarily going to move along

Comment: You could extend the rigid transformation of the sphere to a rigid transformation of the sphere and its interior (or all space). Then the center *would* necessarily move along.

Comment: @David-K's solution fixes that problem, however the more elegant way to think about it (which I tried to hint at in my comments) is that there is a notion of distance between points _in_ the sphere itself (independent from the ambient space). This is the length of the shortest path on the sphere between the two points, which turns out to be a segment of a great circle joining those points. With respect to this distance fiction, the circle $\gamma$ is still the locus of all points equidistant from a centre point, but this centre point now lies in the circle itself.

Comment: @DavidSheard My thinking on this may have been influenced by the last thing I read in your comment, which was "ambient 3D space," so I overlooked the metric on the sphere. For that matter, the circle is also specified by a constant 3D distance from one of its poles on the sphere. So now we have three ways to track it, two of which use points only on the sphere itself.

Comment: @DavidSheard that sounds good!

Comment: @DavidSheard the good part is that we probably don't need to use the distance in the sphere. By the regular distance that should work too right?

Comment: Yes it does work because any isometry (ie rigid motion) of $\mathbb{E}^3$ is uniquely determined by its image on four non coplanar points. Since the sphere contains four such points, any rigid motion of the sphere uniquely extends to a rigid motion of the ambient space, which in particular transports the centre of $\gamma$ in the ambient metric.

Comment: @DavidSheard I meant that the center of the circle in the sphere is also a center with respect to the usual distance, thus the image of the original circle is a meeting of two spheres and thus it must be a circle too

Comment: Yes, I agree, and my comment just rigorously justifies why you can extend the rigid motion of the sphere to the rest of 3D space.